# how to bring corners of two objects together

Tags: transforms

I know it is simple but I cannot do it. i want to bring the top of vertical bar down to match the edge of horizontal bar so they form a shape like a right angle. so yes of course i can bring the vertical bar down and manually approximately position it near the edge of horizontal bar. But i want it to accurately snap. I mean i want the top face of vertical bar to snap to the small side face of horizontal bar. here is what i did: i brought the cursor to the top face of vertical bar. I turned snap on, and chose face and center option so that the top of vertical bar snaps to the center of side face of horizontal bar. but i cannot do it. it doesn't snap. [image]

Comment: What happens when you turn off Proportional Editing? Have you tried Merge By Distance on both objects before moving?

Comment: There is also the snapping method shown in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jfr5ULxQ0Rg that was introduced in Blender 4.0.

Comment: the snapping is really very counterintuitive or simply not working. similar to the video i first select my object and then press G. then i try to snap with all those face edge vertex ... options and it just behaves however it wants nothing  like i want. then i also try with pressing B. now I have somewhat more control select (sometimes) where i want to grab but then i cannot take it to where i want. it just does as it pleases. snapping in blender either really sucks or i simply cannot do it - and I used many drawing programs, cad before

Comment: As there could be a few reasons why you can't get snapping to work like you want it to, the best way that someone could help you would be by looking at your .blend file. You could edit your question and add the file with just the two objects in it, by uploading it to: https://blend-exchange.com/  continued...

Comment: Based on your comment, it appears that there is something you don't understand about snapping in Blender. This is a YouTube video that explains some basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c0Evpf8V3A There isn't likely to be anything in it that will help with this problem. I would also suggest doing a search on YouTube for blender snapping. There are many tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Snap-control on the 3d-view screen.  click on the magnet to turn on and then in my case "Edge" was the selection that worked for me.

[image]

Remember to disable snap afterward or you may think blender is going crazy on you.

Comment: no it doesn't work